# static pthread spinlock initialization exists?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

Is there a static initializer for pthread spin lock?  I looked at pthread.h, and it doesn't seem like there is one.

I am looking for something similar to PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh could you elaborate? thanks!

Comment: Some of constant or macro defined on `header files` but some of them defined in itself library , when defined in library *.dll in win or .so in unix world, you can't access them.

Comment: Ok.  Then, is there a static initializer for pthread spin lock defined in libpthread.so? Thanks.

Comment: if you couldn't find in header yes.

Comment: May I know what macro name then?

Comment: yes you can , for reading doc visit, https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: I don't see any static initializer for spinlock in the link you pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only POSIX control structures for which static initializers are defined seem to be mutex, condition and read-write lock.

Comment: yea, that's what I found so far as well. Moshen's comment made me think that pthread developers had bad coding practice -- putting a macro that is intended to be used by external users in a .c/.cpp. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use constructor and destructor (available in gcc and clang)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static pthread_spinlock_t lock;

__attribute__((constructor))
void lock_constructor () {
    if ( pthread_spin_init ( &lock, 0 ) != 0 ) {
        exit ( 1 );
    }
}

int main () {
    if (
        pthread_spin_lock   ( &lock ) != 0 ||
        pthread_spin_unlock ( &lock ) != 0
    ) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((destructor))
void lock_destructor () {
    if ( pthread_spin_destroy ( &lock ) != 0 ) {
        exit ( 3 );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very interesting one.  Didn't know such feature exists.  Thanks for sharing this trick!